# grails <g:link tag sometimes works and sometimes doesn't>

Tags: grails

The

```
<g:link controller="foo" action="bar">foobar</g:link>
```

tag sometimes works, that is is renders as

```
<a href="grailsapp/foo/bar">foobar</a>
```

and sometimes it doesn't. In this case I'll get a

```
<a href="grailsapp/">foobar</a>
```

Does anyone know what conditions cause this tag to fail to expand? Also is there any way to debug the tag expansion logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not solve your problem or everyone else's, but I had this same problem occur for me. I had a /mywebapp/session/login URL that I wanted to link to, but `<g:link controller="session" action="login">` just resolved to /mywebapp/.

But it turns out that I had mapped my context root "/" to show the login page. I had thought it would redirect, but really it exposed the Session.login page at "/". So, when grails was told to create a link to go to Session.login, the simplest link it could come up with that would take me there was "/". So "/" was correct after all.

If you still can't get it working, but you still need a way to generate links relative to your context root, you can use `<a href="${createLink(uri: '/foo/bar')}">`

Answer (score 1):

To debug - the file you need is at

$GRAILS_HOME\src\java\org\codehaus\groovy\grails\plugins\web\taglib\ApplicationTagLib.groovy

Answer (score 0):

Only one remark which may be useful:

If you are in a file .gsp into the folder:

- view
- controller_name
- your_view.gsp

This works fine: >> `<a href="${createLink(uri: '/foo/bar')}">`

If you are in a file .gsp into the src/template (for example to modify the list.gsp, create.gsp, etc.):

You have to add a backslash like this:`<a href="\${createLink(uri: '/foo/bar')}">`